# Twitter Bootstrap Twipsy doesn't work in Firefox/Chrome but works in IE

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application and I am using Twipsy plugin from Twitter Bootstrap to show validation messages on the client side...

If there is an error, there is a nice twipsy tooltip. But if the user corrects the input field, the twipsy error message is not going away in Firefox and Chrome. It goes away in IE 9.

What is the problem?

Here is the url of the project : http://4aab82026a744a638d04d47f8b428217.cloudapp.net/

If you click on signup without entering the zip, it shows the message.

Same can be observed in the second signup page after entering zip code.

Comment: can you paste your code in something like http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: It's hard to reproduce it in the jsfiddle... But you can easily trouble shoot it in firebug... The twipsy show/hide happens in main.js in the function ShowHideTwipsy() <-- main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable any acceleration mechanisms, i.e. CloudFlare, then delete the DOCTYPE; reload and see if it works; if it does replace your DOCTYPE data with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Site name goes here</title>
```

This should resolve Bootstrap based errors with Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Do you know why twitter removed twipsy from it's new version of bootstrap?